# Use Jq to insert property of an object in another property

Tags: jq

I have a json file that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "account_id": 123, 
    "instances": [
      {"id": 1},
      {"id": 2}
    ]
  },
  {
    "account_id": 456, 
    "instances": [
      {"id": 1}
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to flatten the instances into a single list and insert the account_id into each instance. Here is the result that I want.

```json
[
  {"id": 1, "account_id": 123},
  {"id": 2, "account_id": 123},
  {"id": 1, "account_id": 456}
]
```

---

Here is a alternate solution that I came up with while waiting on an answer.

```
jq '.|map(.instances[]+{"account_id": .account_id})' file.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq '[.[] | .id = .instances[0].id | del(.instances)]' file.json
```

If there are more instances, just iterate over all of them to distribute the account_id to each of them:

```
jq '[.[] | .id = .instances[].id | del(.instances)]' file.json
                           ~~
```

Comment: This worked almost exactly how I wanted. I didn't specify that there could possible be multiple instances in in ".instances".

I modified it account for the spec update:
```
jq '[.[] | .id = .instances[].id | del(.instances)]' file.json
```

Hopefully you can edit you answers to be inline.